# Publishing a Powershell Script with dependencies on custom modules

Tags: powershell, publishing

I've written a powershell script that I want to upload to the PowerShell Gallery (https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/upload).

The dependency tree I have going on is as follows (residing in the same directory level)

- script.ps1
- module1.psm1
- module2.psm1

Where `script`'s contents involves calling `Import-Module` on both modules and will proceed to invoke the functions declared in the 2 modules.

On the Publish Help page, it looks the only choices I have are either using `Publish-Module` or `Publish-Script'. Is there a way to bundle up all 3 of my files into a single upload?